# Access Variable inside onItemClick in Android

Tags: android, variables, listener

I am having issues accessing a variable that is modified inside an `onItemClick`. This is how my code looks like right now:

```
    public String parseXML(ArrayList<String> XML) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, JSONException {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMenu.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, XML);
        AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.outputcities);
        acTextView.setThreshold(1);
        acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

        acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                result = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            }
        });
        TextView yo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sample);
        yo.setText(getResult());
        return result;
    }
```

The `TextView` is currently just outputting `""`, as that is what I initialized it to at the very top (as a global variable). Is there anyway I can access the variable that was changed inside the `onItemClick`? I tried doing it statically and adding a set and get method, but even that didn't result in what I wanted. Please let me know if you need more clarification/code.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Public String result ; -- try that and then --- yo.setText(result );

Answer (score 1):

The code inside `onItemClick` is run after the rest of your `parseXML` method, as it is a `Listener` and the code is not run during the method call. Assuming `result` is a class variable, change your method to look like this:

```
public void parseXML(ArrayList<String> XML) throws IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, JSONException
 {
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainMenu.this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_singlechoice, XML);
     AutoCompleteTextView acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.outputcities);
     acTextView.setThreshold(1);
     acTextView.setAdapter(adapter);

     acTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            result = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            processResult();
        }
    });
 }

public void processResult() {
    TextView yo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample);
    yo.setText(result);
    // Do the rest of your stuff here
    // that you were trying to do with the return value of parseXML
}
```

Comment: Do I not need to pass result into processResult()? Or will the global variable automatically get updated?

Comment: oh yep you're right. thanks a lot...that makes sense. Does it have to do with asynchronous vs synchronous?

Comment: Every part of code above is done on one thread (UI thread) - so you should not worry about `asynchronous vs synchronous`.
OS Android just will call function which is set in `setOnItemClickListener`

Comment: Setting a `Listener` is just saying "do this when the event happens". Same with a `Callback`. So the code is run at a completely different time to the rest of the method. If my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

try declare result variable as a global variable of your class and you'll can get access inside clickListener.